# React Native ios run issue

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am new to react-native and running `yarn ios` on my react native project keeps failing with the following error.

> `** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> CompileC
> /Users/gift/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gainerDemo-eudprqpgpjkdvzechchqincjgjlo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o
> /Users/gift/Desktop/personal
> projects/gainerDemo/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp
> normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in
> target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

`

Answer (score 3):

`Folly` hardly ever works for me.

In your `Podfile`, comment out the line `flipper_post_install(installer)` i.e:

```sh
 # Use a hash to comment within Podfiles and Podspecs.
 # flipper_post_install(installer)
```

Then reinstall pods by running either `npx pod-install` or by typing `pod install` in your Terminal from within the `ios` directory. You have to do this every time you modify the `Podfile` or install a new native binary for iOS.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. well i think the latest version of react-native has some issues so i downgraded `npx react-native init MyApp --version 0.62 ` this work perfectly