# M1 Mac react-native iOS build error (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos

On an M1 Mac, with `npm 8.3.1` & `node 17.4`, when I run `npx react-native run-ios` I receive 2 errors:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/Steven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloSteve-hghgfcwemhoaiacfwlophutqqzbh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SysUio.o /Users/Steven/Documents/Projects/React\ Native/HelloSteve/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
    CompileC /Users/Steven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloSteve-hghgfcwemhoaiacfwlophutqqzbh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NetOps.o /Users/Steven/Documents/Projects/React\ Native/HelloSteve/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/net/NetOps.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69920332/667903), the line `flipper_post_install(installer)` didn't exist in the Podfile.

From [this answer](https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/155#issuecomment-1027704724), I commented out `# use_flipper!()` in the Podfile, ran `pod install` then `npx react-native run-ios` and received a similar error:

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/Steven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloSteve-hghgfcwemhoaiacfwlophutqqzbh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SysUio.o /Users/Steven/Documents/Projects/React\ Native/HelloSteve/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I tried the [solution here](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1670#issuecomment-946249692), (commenting out the line `typedef uint8_t clockid_t;` in [Time.h](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/portability/Time.h#L52)) but that didn't work either.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please know me, which version of react native is being used?

Comment: @VickyAhuja, version `0.67.2`.

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this issue but not on M1 Mac

I found that if I create a project in a folder that **contain a white space** *Learning RN/NewProject*, there're an error when we run pod install

I tried to **remove the whitespace** in folder name *LearningRN/NewProject* and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when updating the project target OS version.

Actually Xcode will ask you to change the target OS version for the different packages, which then lead to not finding the RCT package anymore for me.

So when xcode tells you there is a good option to change the target settings for different pods, be very careful with that. Either do it step by step and try out or leave it as is, as long as it is building and running.

`npm install` then `pod install` respectively `arch -x86_64 pod install` since I am also running on M1.

Since it might have to do something with that as well I would also disable arm64 in xcode your projects target build phases under build settings "excluded architectures" and only install pods with `arch -x86_64 pod install`.

Comment: `I would also disable arm64 in build phases and only install pods with arch -x86_64.` - how do we do this, please?

Comment: in xcode go to the project target and there to the tab build settings - there you can put arm64 under excluded architectures.. then install pods ONLY with arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean `then install pods ONLY with arch -x86_64 pod install`? Do I need to uninstall old `arm64` pods first? If so, how, please?

Comment: My way to do the same was actually setting up a new RN project and copy over all the files afterwards. Then getting pods installed with only the arch x86_64. Important is to clean the pods and install everything just for one arch so it does not get mixed up, which will probably lead to the same issue after a while.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open your Xcode project.

2.Navigate to your project's target (usually named after your app) in the Project Navigator on the left.

3.Go to the "Build Settings" tab.

4.Search for the "Excluded Architectures" setting.

5.Add the arm64 architecture to the list of excluded architectures.

6.Save your project settings.

After making this change, you can run pod install to ensure that the pods are only installed with the x86_64 architecture.