# react-native iOS build fails (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

On a Mac with intel chip, when I run `react-native run-ios` to start my react-native app on iOS simulator, I get the following error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/katya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hcieikwfdnipendckclmykmjnojv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SingletonStackTrace.o /Users/katya/Documents/MyApp/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/detail/SingletonStackTrace.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

MacOS - Sonoma 14.0

Processor - 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7

react-native -  "^0.70.6"

XCode - 15

I've seen this question already: [M1 Mac react-native iOS build error (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030835/m1-mac-react-native-ios-build-error-in-target-rct-folly-from-project-pods)
But I don't have M1 chip, and I also don't have a whitespace in my project name. So the answers from this question did not work for me

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: yeah had to update react-native and it worked. I went  back to using XCode 14 until I finished updating, it ran fine on Xcode14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to update react native to latest version. The version we used did not run on XCode 15. It runs on Xcode 14 fine though, so either updating react-native or using XCode 14 worked for me